# Cytoscape is installed on my mac but will not open

Tags: cytoscape

I've tried installing and reinstalling both Cytoscape and Java.  I'm kinda ignorant when it comes to these things so I would love detailed help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us which version of the OS, which version of Cytoscape, and which version of Java you have?  That will help us diagnose what might be going on.

-- scooter

Comment: macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4.      Cytoscape 3.8.0      and Java 8 Update 251

Comment: Any thoughts on a fix?

Comment: Hi Dale,  Cytoscape 3.8 requires Java 11.